# mysql - Latest record with matching value and having the latest be positive

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, having, getlatest

I am posting for the first time.

I have been trying to figure out the issue with this report.
In this report,i want to show the serial numbers for the products that were sold and not returned (+ not - price) most recently.

I want to check whether a product has been marked sold if it was sold last and not returned last.

This is how I have done, I think I may need to subquery it but I am unable to figure out the first part.

```
SELECT 
    ps.serial,p.upc,p.name,so.date_sold 
FROM 
    store_orders so 
    LEFT JOIN store_order_products sop ON so.id = sop.order_id
    LEFT JOIN products p ON sop.product_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN product_serials ps ON ps.serial = sop.product_serial
WHERE 
    (CAST(so.date_sold AS DATE) BETWEEN '2013-4-15' AND '2013-5-15')
    AND ps.deleted = '0' AND sop.price > 0
ORDER BY 
    sop.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It is returning the products that may have been returned last instead of only sold last.

```
`ID Serial  Price
1: 8332-83 10.00
2: 8332-83 -10.00
Dont want to see this because it was returned last, not sold last

ID Serial  Price
2: 8332-82 10.00
1: 8332-82 -10.00
This was sold last not returned so looking to see this serial`
```

Please help.
Thanks in advance.
Joe

Comment: Can you provide a sample input/output?

Comment: Hope that cleared up my question better.

Comment: Still looking for help?
Just looking to sort,group,with price being > 0???

Answer (score 1):

Ok, figured it out thanks to myself. But for anyone else with this kind of issue, here you go.

TRIPLE NESTY, lol

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 
    so.id,sop.product_serial,p.upc,sop.price,p.name,so.date_sold 
FROM 
    store_orders so 
    LEFT JOIN store_order_products sop ON so.id = sop.order_id
    LEFT JOIN products p ON sop.product_id = p.id 
    LEFT JOIN product_serials ps ON ps.serial = sop.product_serial
WHERE ps.deleted = '0' AND so.store_id = '$store_id'
ORDER BY 
    sop.id DESC
LIMIT 1000
) AS t
GROUP BY t.product_serial
) AS t2
WHERE t2.price > 0
```